# クライアントアプリ（.exe）の入力ボックスに値を自動入力させるアプリ

Tags: javascript, batch-file

クライアントアプリ（.exe）で、実行すると入力フォームが起動し入力ボックスがあるアプリがあります。
このアプリは繰り返し使用しするため何度も入力ボックスに値を入力し直さなければならず、この入力ボックスに自動で値を入れるツールを開発しようと思います。
現在batとjavascriptで開発を検討しているのですが、このツールは実装可能なものでしょうか？
もし実装可能であれば方向性をご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: このサイトではアイデア段階の可否は扱いにくいですね。もっと具体的なシステム/ソフトウェア構成や作業手順の情報とか、プログラミングの段階まで詳細化した情報を追記してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
クライアントアプリはi-Reporterというサービスのバージョンアップ用で、アップデート対象のDB名やユーザー名などを入力すれば対象のDBがアップデートされるというものです。
アップデート対象のDBが20以上あるため入力を自動化できないかと思い質問をさせていただきました。
クライアントアプリはexeファイルしかないため詳細不明な状況です。

Comment: この製品/会社でしょうかね。[ConMas iｰReporter](https://conmas.jp/) 7年以上でこれだけの導入実績があるなら、同様の悩みを持つユーザーが山ほど居そうですが、ディーラーとか開発元に対処方法の有無を聞いてみたらどうでしょう。BatchとJavaScriptだと扱える分野が要求されるものと連携しそうにないので難しいでしょう。敢えて言えば[UiPath JavaScript SDK for Robot](https://www.uipath.com/community/rpa-community-blog/introducing-uipath-robot-javascript-sdk)とか[electron@5.0.0でkeytar@4.6.0をWindowsで使う2020年版](https://officeforest.org/wp/2020/03/23/electron5-0-0%E3%81%A7keytar4-6-0%E3%82%92windows%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%862020%E5%B9%B4%E7%89%88/)とかでしょうか。Batch/JavaScriptにこだわらず素直にメジャーなRPAソフトを使った方が良さそうですが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。クライアントアプリへの入力ツールは存在したのですが、最新版のクライアントアプリでフォームがバージョンアップされて非対応になってしまい再度作成することになりました。
（既存入力ツールもexeファイルしか存在せず、製作者も退社済の状況です）

製品メーカー問い合わせし代替ツールの有無確認と、別の方法（RPAソフト等）を検討してみます。

ご回答いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

対象となるOSはWindowsでしょうか？
キーボード操作だけで操作が可能なのであればJavaScript（正確にはJScript）でキーボード操作をするのは難しくはありません。

例えば以下のような感じかと思います。

```js
shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell')
// クライアントアプリを立ち上げる（この例ではメモ帳）
shell.Run('notepad.exe')
// クライアントアプリが立ち上がるまで待つ
WScript.Sleep(10000)

// ボタンへフォーカス
shell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
WScript.Sleep(300)

// ボタンを押す
shell.SendKeys('{SPACE}')
WScript.Sleep(300)

// フォーカス移動
shell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
WScript.Sleep(300)

// テキスト入力
shell.SendKeys('ABCDE')
```

Comment: ＞対象となるOSはWindowsでしょうか？
→Windowsです

ご教示いただいたコードを実行したところ上手く動作いたしました。
クライアントアプリ動作はまだ未検証ですが、問題なく動作すればご教示いただいたJScriptを採用する可能性が高いです。

ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

バッチでは厳しいですが、dotnetのUI Automationをpowershellから使えば望むことができます。
参考サイトは、[powershellで電卓を動かす例。](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=12193)

あと、外部ツールを使ってよいなら、
autoit
auto hot key
uwsc
などのウインドウズ自動化ツールを使えば簡単だと思います。

Comment: powershellの参考サイトありがとうございます。

外部ツールでも問題ありません。ウインドウズ自動化ツールでの実施も検討してみます。

ご回答ありがとうございました。